# Prettytable vrules and hrules to none

Tags: python, prettytable

I have the following code which produces pretty table. What i would like to do is to remove the vrules or hrules. The code i have is not doing anything. Could you please advise why? Just to make sure, vrules is the vertical lines

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable, FRAME, HEADER, NONE
PrettyTable().hrules = NONE
# x = PrettyTable()
# x.hrules = NONE
myTable = PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Class", "Section", "Percentage"])
myTable.title = 'Big Bang Theory'
  
# Add rows
myTable.add_row(["Leanord", "X", "B", "91.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Penny", "X", "C", "63.5 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Howard", "X", "A", "90.23 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Bernadette", "X", "D", "92.7 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Sheldon", "X", "A", "98.2 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Raj", "X", "B", "88.1 %"])
myTable.add_row(["Amy", "X", "B", "95.0 %"])
PrettyTable().vrules = NONE
print(myTable.get_string(sort_key=operator.itemgetter(1, 3), sortby="Section"))
```

It is still producing the same table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|               Big Bang Theory               |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
| Student Name | Class | Section | Percentage |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
|     Amy      |   X   |    B    |   95.0 %   |
|  Bernadette  |   X   |    D    |   92.7 %   |
|    Howard    |   X   |    A    |  90.23 %   |
|   Leanord    |   X   |    B    |   91.2 %   |
|    Penny     |   X   |    C    |   63.5 %   |
|     Raj      |   X   |    B    |   88.1 %   |
|   Sheldon    |   X   |    A    |   98.2 %   |
+--------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/) you can:

```
>>> myTable = PrettyTable()
>>> myTable.hrules, myTable.vrules = NONE, NONE
>>> myTable.title = 'Big Bang Theory' # this won't show, see below
>>> myTable.field_names = ["Student Name", "Class", "Section", "Percentage"]
>>> myTable.add_row(["Leanord", "X", "B", "91.2 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Penny", "X", "C", "63.5 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Howard", "X", "A", "90.23 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Bernadette", "X", "D", "92.7 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Sheldon", "X", "A", "98.2 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Raj", "X", "B", "88.1 %"])
>>> myTable.add_row(["Amy", "X", "B", "95.0 %"])
>>> print(myTable.get_string(sort_key=operator.itemgetter(1, 3), sortby="Section"))
  Student Name   Class   Section   Percentage  
      Amy          X        B        95.0 %    
   Bernadette      X        D        92.7 %    
     Howard        X        A       90.23 %    
    Leanord        X        B        91.2 %    
     Penny         X        C        63.5 %    
      Raj          X        B        88.1 %    
    Sheldon        X        A        98.2 %
```

The above has an issue. That is, namely, that it will *not* show the title. To have the title shown you need to install [PTable](https://pypi.org/project/PTable/). Once you do that the code above, produces:

```py
                Big Bang Theory                
  Student Name   Class   Section   Percentage  
      Amy          X        B        95.0 %    
   Bernadette      X        D        92.7 %    
     Howard        X        A       90.23 %    
    Leanord        X        B        91.2 %    
     Penny         X        C        63.5 %    
      Raj          X        B        88.1 %    
    Sheldon        X        A        98.2 %
```